# Cannot understand with sklearn's PolynomialFeatures

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, polynomials

Need help in sklearn's Polynomial Features. It works quite well with one feature but whenever I add multiple features, it also outputs some values in the array besides the values raised to the power of the degrees.
For ex: For this array,

```
X=np.array([[230.1,37.8,69.2]])
```

when I try to

```
X_poly=poly.fit_transform(X)
```

It outputs

```
[[ 1.00000000e+00 2.30100000e+02 3.78000000e+01 6.92000000e+01
5.29460100e+04 8.69778000e+03 1.59229200e+04 1.42884000e+03
2.61576000e+03 4.78864000e+03]]
```

Here, what is `8.69778000e+03,1.59229200e+04,2.61576000e+03` ?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If you have features `[a, b, c]` the default polynomial features(in `sklearn` the degree is 2) should be `[1, a, b, c, a^2, b^2, c^2, ab, bc, ca]`.

`2.61576000e+03` is `37.8x62.2=2615,76` (`2615,76 = 2.61576000 x 10^3`)

In a simple way with the `PolynomialFeatures` you can create new features. There is a good reference [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html). Of course there are and disadvantages("Overfitting") of using `PolynomialFeatures`(see [here](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-to-use-higher-order-polynomials-in-Lagranges-interpolation)).

**Edit:**
We have to be careful when using the polynomial features. The formula for calculating the number of the polynomial features is `N(n,d)=C(n+d,d)` where `n` is the number of the features, `d` is the degree of the polynomial, `C` is binomial coefficient(combination). In our case the number is `C(3+2,2)=5!/(5-2)!2!=10` but when the number of features or the degree is height the polynomial features becomes too many. For example:

```
N(100,2)=5151
N(100,5)=96560646
```

So in this case you may need to apply **regularization** to penalize some of the weights. It is quite possible that the algorithm will start to suffer from [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality) ([here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-curse-of-dimensionality) is also a very nice discussion).

Comment: Why does it gives ab,bc,ca?

Comment: @TechieBoy101: It's polynomial features, not monomial features. There's nothing restricting it to only one variable at a time.

Comment: @TechieBoy101, The default `PolynomialFeatures` in `sklearn` includes all polynomial combinations. You can add `interaction_only=True` to exclude the powers like `a^2, b^2, c^2`. Of course you can exclude the interaction if your model performs better - the `PolynomialFeatures` are a simple way to derive new  features (in some artificial manner).

Comment: The polynomial features formula is incorrect, although the location for  `bc` is correct. See `poly.get_feature_names(['a','b','c'])`, which will give `['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a^2', 'a b', 'a c', 'b^2', 'b c', 'c^2']`.

Comment: @dim when we add the additional features by raising data into a power, don't we introduce multicolinearity?

Comment: In PolynomialFeatures what does fit() and transform() do exactly? Because even though I read the documentation I don't understand it, I try to give you an analogy with what fit() and transform() do in StandardScaler, but it doesn't seem to make sense; since the fit() and transform() methods do different things in both cases.

Answer (score 17):

PolynomialFeatures generates a new matrix with all polynomial combinations of features with given degree.

Like [a] will be converted into [1,a,a^2] for degree 2.

You can visualize input being transformed into matrix generated by PolynomialFeatures.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a = a[:,np.newaxis]
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
a_poly = poly.fit_transform(a)
print(a_poly)
```

Output:

```
 [[ 1.  1.  1.]
 [ 1.  2.  4.]
 [ 1.  3.  9.]
 [ 1.  4. 16.]
 [ 1.  5. 25.]]
```

You can see matrix generated in form of [1,a,a^2]

To observe polynomial features on scatter plot, let's use number 1-100.

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

#Making 1-100 numbers
a = np.arange(1,100,1)
a = a[:,np.newaxis]

#Scaling data with 0 mean and 1 standard Deviation, so it can be observed easily
scaler = StandardScaler()
a = scaler.fit_transform(a)

#Applying PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures(degree=2)
a_poly = poly.fit_transform(a)

#Flattening Polynomial feature matrix (Creating 1D array), so it can be plotted. 
a_poly = a_poly.flatten()
#Creating array of size a_poly with number series. (For plotting)
xarr = np.arange(1,a_poly.size+1,1)

#Plotting
plt.scatter(xarr,a_poly)
plt.title("Degree 2 Polynomial")
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: 2 Degree]

Changing degree=3 ,we get:

[image: 3 Degree]

Answer (score 6):

The general way to check the features is with [`poly.get_feature_names()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html#sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.get_feature_names). In this case, it would be

```py
>>> poly.get_feature_names(['a','b','c'])
    ['1', 'a', 'b', 'c', 'a^2', 'a b', 'a c', 'b^2', 'b c', 'c^2']
```

and `8.69778000e+03,1.59229200e+04,2.61576000e+03` would correspond to the `a*b`, `a*c` and `b*c`terms, correspondingly.

Answer (score 2):

You have 3-dimensional data and the following code generates all poly features of degree 2:

```
X=np.array([[230.1,37.8,69.2]])
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
poly = PolynomialFeatures()
X_poly=poly.fit_transform(X)
X_poly
#array([[  1.00000000e+00,   2.30100000e+02,   3.78000000e+01,
#      6.92000000e+01,   5.29460100e+04,   8.69778000e+03,
#      1.59229200e+04,   1.42884000e+03,   2.61576000e+03,
#      4.78864000e+03]])
```

This can also be generated with the following code:

```
a, b, c = 230.1, 37.8, 69.2 # 3-dimensional data
np.array([[1,a,b,c,a**2,a*b,c*a,b**2,b*c,c**2]]) # all possible degree-2 polynomial features
# array([[  1.00000000e+00,   2.30100000e+02,   3.78000000e+01,
      6.92000000e+01,   5.29460100e+04,   8.69778000e+03,
      1.59229200e+04,   1.42884000e+03,   2.61576000e+03,
      4.78864000e+03]])
```

Comment: What about when we have an array of shape `(11, 1)` , how then would be all possible features?

Answer (score 1):

According scikit's [0.23 docs](https://scikit-learn.org/0.23/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html) (and as far back as [0.15](https://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html)), `PolynomialFeatures` will

> [generate] a new feature matrix consisting of all polynomial combinations of the features with degree less than or equal to the specified degree. ***For example, if an input sample is two dimensional and of the form [a, b], the degree-2 polynomial features are [1, a, b, a^2, ab, b^2].***